# Частичная инициализация членов класса

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, инициализация, c++20

Почему GCC в режиме С++20 возвращает `0`, а в режиме С++17 отказывается успешно компилировать? [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:4,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:4),source:%27int+main()+%7B%0A++++using+A+%3D+struct+%7B+int+x,+y%3B+%7D%3B%0A++++return+static_cast%3CA%3E(42).y%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:99.99999999999999,l:%274%27,m:23.60017205681066,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:conformance,i:(compilers:!((compilerId:gsnapshot,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O2%27),(compilerId:gsnapshot,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-O2%27)),editorid:1,langId:c%2B%2B,libs:!()),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Conformance+Viewer+(Editor+%231)+2/10%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:25.17351686059804,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O2%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:33.33333333333333,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:51.22631108259129,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
int main() {
    using A = struct { int x, y; };
    return static_cast<A>(42).y;
}
```

> error: no matching function for call to 'main()::<unnamed struct>::._anon_0(int)'

Comment: А что вы хотите сделать этим кодом?

Comment: @SpaceResearcher частично проинициализировать `A`

Comment: `return A{42}.y;`

Answer (score 2):

Это работает в C++20, потому что эта структура имеет *aggregate type*, для которого в определение `static_cast` ввели дополнительный пункт.

[[expr.static.cast]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.static.cast#4):

> **An expression E can be explicitly converted to a type T** if there is an
> implicit conversion sequence
> ([[over.best.ics]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/over.best.ics))
> from E to T, if overload resolution for a direct-initialization
> ([[dcl.init]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.init)) of
> an object or reference of type T from E would find at least one viable
> function
> ([[over.match.viable]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/over.match.viable)),
> or **if T is an aggregate type
> ([[dcl.init.aggr]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.init.aggr))
> having a first element x and there is an implicit conversion sequence
> from E to the type of x**. ...

В С++17 этого пункта нет.

[[expr.static.cast]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std17/expr.static.cast#4):

> An expression e can be explicitly converted to a type T if there is an
> *implicit conversion sequence* from e to T, or if overload resolution for a *direct-initialization* of an object or reference of type T from
> e would find at least one viable function
> ([[over.match.viable]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std17/over.match.viable)).
> ...

Вместо этого пытаемся неявно привести `42` к `A`, что невозможно, т.к. нет соответствующего оператора/конструктора. Тогда пытаемся выполнить *direct-initialization* вида `A(42)`. Однако в [определении *direct-initialization* в С++17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std17/dcl.init#17.6) отсутствует следующий пункт из С++20, который позволяет это сделать.

[[dcl.init]/16.6.2.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.init#general-16.6.2.2):

> Otherwise, **if the initialization is direct-initialization**, or if it is
> copy-initialization where the cv-unqualified version of the source
> type is the same class as, or a derived class of, the class of the
> destination, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors
> are enumerated
> ([[over.match.ctor]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/over.match.ctor)),
> and the best one is chosen through overload resolution
> ([[over.match]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/over.match)).
> Then:
>
> - ...
> - Otherwise, **if no constructor is viable, the destination type is an aggregate class, and the initializer is a parenthesized
>   *expression-list*, the object is initialized as follows**. ...
> - ...

Почему в C++20 второй элемент структуры равен `0`, а не чему-либо другому (например, *indeterminate value*)? Это следует из следующих пунктов.

[[expr.static.cast]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/expr.static.cast#4):

> ... Otherwise, the result object is direct-initialized from E. ...

[[dcl.init]/16.6.2.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.init#general-16.6.2.2):

> ... Let e<sub>1</sub>, …, e<sub>n</sub> be the elements of the
> aggregate
> ([[dcl.init.aggr]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.init#aggr)).
> Let x<sub>1</sub>, …, x<sub>k</sub> be the elements of the
> *expression-list*. If k is greater than n, the program is ill-formed. The element e<sub>i</sub> is copy-initialized with x<sub>i</sub> for 1
> ≤ i ≤ k. **The remaining elements** are initialized with their default
> member initializers, if any, and otherwise **are value-initialized**.
> ...

[[dcl.init]/8.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.init#general-8.3):

> To *value-initialize* an object of type T means:
>
> - ...
> - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

[[dcl.init]/6.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/std20/dcl.init#general-6.1):

> To *zero-initialize* an object or reference of type T means:
>
> - if T is a *scalar type*, the object is initialized to the value obtained by converting the integer literal `0` (zero) to T;
> - ...